# How to convert between Sum Of Products and Product of sums?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have a Boolean expression. we'll call it `F`.

for instance, `F = ab' + ad + c'd + d'`.

Assuming I did all the necessary steps too get `F` complement , i.e. `F'`.

I got: `F' = b'd + ac'd'`.

How do I get the `Product of sums` form of `F`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$F=(F')'=(b'd+ac'd\,')'=(b'd)'(ac'd\,')'=(b+d\,')(a'+c+d)\;.$$

(Note: I did not check your $F'$.)

Because of the way the De Morgan laws work, the complement of a product of sums is always a sum of products, and the complement of a sum of products is always a product of sums.

Comment: Thank you, but that is exactly what I've got (on my paper...) and it doesn't work .. are you sure it's right?

Comment: @user1798362: I’m sure that it would be right if your $F'$ were right. The problem is that your $F'$ is wrong: I get $a'b'cd+ab'c'd'$ for $F'$.

Answer (score 0):

F = ab' + ad + c'd + d'

F'= (ab' + ad + c'd + d')'
  = (ab')' . (ad)' . (c'd)' . (d')'  ---> a'.b' =(a'+b') De Morgans law
  = (a'+b)(a'+b')(c+d')(d)

Hence Product of sums.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Thank you for your answer! It is, however, rather difficult to read. For some basic information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latexhelp/notation).

Comment: I've been asking it a 1 year ago .. as you can guess it's not relevant anymore

Comment: Hi from 7 years in the future to let you know that it's still relevant! Always worth taking the time to improve an answer since the Q&A format is just as much about helping future visitors as it is the OP. Nonetheless, this answerer has unregistered but the sentiment stands...

Answer (score -1):

If the boolean expression is AB+BC.Then the product of sum expression is (A+B)(B+C).To find this, the complement of sum product expression is the product of sum expression.                                                                        (AB+BC)'=A'B'+B'C'
           By applying DEMORGANS LAW
            =(A'+B')(B'+C')
       Now,
      (A'+B')'(B'+C')'=(A+B)(B+C).